# Apps Script onEdit Change Log

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an AppsScript beginnger trying to write a script to automate tracking in a spreadsheet i.e. wherever the status column in a sheet is changed (from dropdown) add to a separate Change Long tab keeping a record of previous value, new value, who made the change and when.

I have started below but keep hitting errors. Any help would be much appreciated!

```html
      function onEdit(e) {  
  var changelogSheetName = "Change Log";
  var ss = "Form Responses 4"
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var newValue = cell.getValue(); 
  var typeChange = "Edit";
  //var customer = sheet.getRange('Form Responses 4!E1').getValue();
  
  var monColumn = 10;
  var startRow = 760;
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();

    if (currentSheetName == changelogSheetName) return;
  
  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);

  if (changelogSheet == null) {
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets()); 
   }
  
  changelogSheet.getRange('A1:G1').setBackground('#E0E0E0');  
changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet", "Cell", "Type", "New Value", "User"]);  
  
      changelogSheet.deleteColumns(8,19);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 170);
    changelogSheet.setColumnWidth(7, 170);
    changelogSheet.protect();
  
    var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  
     changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp,typeChange, newValue,customer, user]); }
```

Comment: Too many undefined variable to provide you with any assistance

Answer (score 0):

This uses an installable trigger to create a  changelog using a spreadsheet for the log.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const excl=['excluded sheet names'];
  if(~excl.indexOf(sh.getName()))return;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid).getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([new Date(),Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),sh.getName(),e.oldValue,e.value,e.range.getA1Notation()]);
}
```

gobj.globals.testsourceid is the id  of the change log spreadsheet.

[onedit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Log Sheet:

| 5/8/2021 23:34:26 | Redacted | Sheet1 |  | 33 | A1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/8/2021 23:34:30 | Redacted | Sheet1 |  | 44 | C2 |
| 5/8/2021 23:34:36 | Redacted | Sheet3 |  | 88 | F10 |
| 5/8/2021 23:35:04 | Redacted | Sheet3 | 88 | 10 | F10 |
| 5/8/2021 23:35:14 | Redacted | Sheet1 | 33 | 77 | A1 |
| 5/8/2021 23:35:39 | Redacted | Sheet1 | 44 | 99 | C2 |